# UIButton not receiving IBAction

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, ibaction, hittest

I have what should be a very simple thing to do.  I'm working on someone else's code, and I want to enlarge a `UIButton` because it's too small for users.  I made it bigger in the storyboard, but when I run the app, the associated `IBAction` only gets hit when touching where the original rectangle was before I changed it.  The button is still visibly larger, but only a portion of it receives touch events.  Does anyone know what else might be at play here?

Note: there are no views on top of the new area that the button occupies, so I don't think the touches get picked up by a view on top.

Comment: Some other view with a gesture? Auto resizing changing the button at runtime? Many options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the IBAction hooked up to "touch up inside" in Interface Builder/Storyboard? I've made mistakes where I hook it up with a different kind of event, which exhibits behaviours like you're experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

Something to check is whether the UIButton has an ancestor view (i.e. a view in its superview chain) that is the smaller size. Hit-tests only pass down the view hierarchy if the touch is contained within the view so a smaller superview will stop the touches outside its bounds, even if the touch is inside the button.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  There was a view being programmatically added on top of the button.  It's `origin.x` was being hardcoded to where the buttons width use to end.